# fortran write output: all variables in a line

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

sorry,

I try to write a file.dat whit a lot of columns (11) with different format (1.4e-12, 10...)

when i try ro write the code i use the following fortran command:

```
                 WRITE(7,*) id,t,a,e,inc,capom,omega,capm,mass,radius
```

but each line in the original file is now write in multiply lines.

From:

> 1222221 0.0 10.0 0.0 3.1415927 0.0 0.0 3.7828348 9.0E-9 4.0E-6

to:

> 1222221  0.000000000000000E+000   10.0000000000000
>     0.000000000000000E+000  0.000000000000000E+000  0.000000000000000E+000
>     0.000000000000000E+000   1.67102026939392       9.000000189551827E-010
>     3.999999989900971E-006

How can i resolve this?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the format you want. You can do this by using

- `i0` to specify some unknown width integer
- `f4.1` to specify an up-to 2 digit real plus 1 decimal place (min of 0.0 and max of 99.9)
- `f9.7` to specify an up-to 1 digit real plut 7 decimal places (fits pi nicely there)
- `es10.1` to specify an up-to 8 digit scientific notation real with a single decimal place (will fit 9e-9 nicely)
- `1x` to specify a space between each number

These can be used together to get

```
write(7,'(i0,1x,3(f4.1,1x),f9.7,1x,2(f4.1,1x),2(es10.1,1x))') &
                              id,t,a,e,inc,capom,omega,capm,mass,radius
```