# FORTRAN WRITE in one line only (prevent newline or carriage returns)

Tags: fortran, line, carriage-return

Okay, so here is my Fortran code:

```
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: U_FLOW = 33
OPEN(UNIT=U_FLOW, FILE='Result_FLOW.txt', STATUS='REPLACE', FORM='FORMATTED')
WRITE(U_FLOW, *) '   time (s)        , abasgagawega (fraction), change in awgeaweara (aaaw),' , &
                '   vgwggrarharfg (aerhag), areahahbfwe (awerhh),   awerhaergargh (g)   ,'   , &
                '  aerhaawrhthaa (rhae),   aerh(z) = ?          ,   aerhaehahahh (aerh),  '  , &
                '   time step (s)                                                        '
```

Here is what I get:

```
    time (s)        , abasgagawega (fraction), change in awgeaweara (aaaw),
    vgwggrarharfg (aerhag), areahahbfwe (awerhh),   awerhaergargh (g)   ,
   aerhaawrhthaa (rhae),   aerh(z) = ?          ,   aerhaehahahh (aerh),  
    time step (s)
```

How do I stop the carriage returns from appearing in the middle of the printed line? I want this all to print on one line in my text file. I looked here but ultimately the guy did not answer the question:
[fortran-write-output-all-variables-in-a-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979009/fortran-write-output-all-variables-in-a-line)

Comment: The answer in the question you linked to is the answer to your problem.  If you use a `*` as a format specifier, you are saying that you don't care what the output looks like in detail.  One of those details is the number of lines that the output will take.  If you want it to only take one line, then you should not use `*`.

Comment: @IanH, that should be an answer (and the question should be closed as duplicate...)

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407232/avoid-newline-in-list-directed-output-with-intel-fortran-complier . Still looking for a best duplicate.

Comment: I think the one linked in the question is the best to ref as dup.  FWIW the format here can be just `(4a)`

Comment: The format specifier "(4a)" did the trick. Thanks for the help!